# How to implement optional branches in fluent interfaces

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

I'm currently creating a fluent interface and I'm not 100% sure what's the best way to implement optional branches. A little example:

```
// Normal service registration
.AddService(myService)
// Service registration with additional parameters
.AddService(myOtherService).WithParameter(ServiceParam.Timeout, 100)
.AddService(myThirdService)
```

Now, I'm not really sure which return types AddService() and WithParameter() should have. The base interface provides `AddService` which must returns something supporting `WithParameter` AND `AddService`. Would you recommend to have the following structure (pseudo-code):

```
interface FluentStart
{
    AddService
}

interface FluentServiceConfiguration
{
    WithParameter
}
```

and finally, AddService would return an interface of:

```
interface FluentStartORFluentServiceConfiguration
    : FluentStart
    , FluentServiceConfiguration
```

? Is there any other (better) way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda expression:

```
interface FluentStart
{
    AddService( service );
    AddService( service, Action<FluentServiceConfiguration> config );
}

// Normal service registration
.AddService(myService)
// Service registration with additional parameters
.AddService(myOtherService, x => x.WithParameter(ServiceParam.Timeout, 100))
.AddService(myThirdService)
```

Comment: This kind of loses the fluent approach, doesn't it?

Comment: I believe it's pretty fluent

Comment: Fluent interfaces isn't about being able to read it out loud and creating perfect english sentences. It's about giving an API that is really fluid.